# Calculating area of vegetated areas within building buffers in FME

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I have two feature layers, buildings buffered with 50 meter and a polygon layer containing vegetation occurence. I want to compute the area of vegetation within each 50 meter buffer. How do I go ahead to do this?
I have been working with the following workflow:

- Bufferer to buffer the buildings with 50 meter
- Clipper to clip the vegetation to the buffers
- Spatial filter where "BuildingBuffers OGC-Contains Vegetation". The vegetation is the candidate.
- Area calculator of the resulting areas
- Statistic Calculator to sum the calculated vegetation area for each building ID.

The result is missing data for many of the building buffers. I think one problem is that the vegetated areas are only counted once, while in reality they can be included in many of the building buffers. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: I'm using FME for the analysis

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think if you change the Overlapping Clippers parameter to Clip Interim Results, it should give you the result you need.

From the documentation:

[image]

As you can see, Clip Interim creates a polygon for each of the overlapping clippers, so you will get a vegetation piece for every overlap.